# Unable to identify Wbfgrid if it has large number of rows

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have a weird situation where QTP will not identify a WBFgrid if it has a large(800+) rows of data. However it will identify if it has (5-100) rows of data.

Has anyone seen this behavior before and knows of a way to solve this using a QTP setting or something.

Just so people know I was able to come up with a work around for this problem by using DOM. What I am looking for is a way to make it work naturally using QPT.

Comment: Could it be that when the grid has a large row count, it takes so long to populate it that QTP looks at the AUT GUI too soon, so it sees an incomplete, or nonresponsive, GUI? What if you take the associated test object in OR manager and try to highlight the GUI object after the CPU has come to an idle state (with the grid displayed)? I´m 50% sure you AUT either fakes a preview which QTP does not recognize as a grid, or there is some timing problem.

Comment: I have run this flow in debug mode and i actually wait till the grid is displayed and then run code related to the grid still it doesn't work. I am able to highlight/interact with other objects on the page except the grid after it is populated. With the grid displayed i can highlight it if it has fewer rows but not when it has 800+ rows. I am not sure how to verify if the preview is being faked, Is that even possible?

Comment: Well for example some Aldus products used to show a fake toolbar and menubar so it looks like the app already has loaded, while it was still loading. So yes that would be possible -- but I highly doubt this is the case here.

Comment: "I am able to highlight/interact with other objects on the page except the grid after it is populated." Does this mean you can, or cannot, access the grid contents MANUALLY in the 800+ row case?

Comment: manually i can access the grid and other objects on the page it is only when i try to do it through UFT that i have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with UFT, whenever I had more than 800 rows of data UFT would not recognize the WBFGrid.

To overcome this problem I accessed the page's internal property and identified the WBFGrid using it's ID. The final code looked something like this.

```
Set objWbfGrid = pgSrch.Object.getElementById("WBFGrid_ID")

'Set rows object
Set objWbfRows = objWbfGrid.childNodes(0).childNodes

intRowCount = objWbfRows.length

For intWbfRow = 1 To intRowCount - 1 Step 1 'skip the first row as it is the header
    Set objCols = objWbfRows.Item(intWbfRow).childNodes

    Set objCell = objCols.Item(0) 'The first column has index 0

    strCellValue = Trim(objCell.childNodes.Item(0).nodeValue)

    'Verify the Distance from member is greater than 30
    If strCellValue = "What I was looking for" Then
        blnMatchFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```